# Does pthread_cancel free up the thread stack?

Tags: pthreads, posix

Can anyone help me??. I am trying to kill them, but, that will require a signal. So, I thought of using cancel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely `pthread_cancel` will not free the thread's stack, given that the canceled thread may continue to execute for some time, for example, executing cancellation handlers.

Thread resources are cleaned up after both `pthread_detach` were called on the thread and the thread has terminated (which is possible to occur in either order).

Comment: Instead of `pthread_detach`, you could `pthread_join`. However, even that is not *guaranteed* to free the thread stack (as in: give it back to the OS) -- the thread library may decide to hold on to it for the next thread you are going to create.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Could you please provide a link to this: *even that is not guaranteed to free the thread stack* ?